# how to change port for SFTP connection in Debian8

Tags: ssh, sftp, debian-jessie

i changed default SSH port with ssh in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and set it to 2211. now i can connect to server with ssh and new port, but in `FileZilla`  when i try to connect to server with this new port (2211) for send some files to server, it generates an error :

```
Error:  Cannot establish FTP connection to an SFTP server. Please select proper protocol.
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

what's the problem? and how can i solve it?
tanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that filezilla is trying to connect using FTP protocol via SSH port. You can force it to switch to SFTP protocl by specifying the hostname like:

```
sftp://server_ip
```